# AJAX back button menu issue

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm developing web site using jquery $.ajax to load content of different pages that I have in content/ directory. I also use hashtags to activate back button, reload, etc.

BUT. I have main menu with active items, and if I navigate between the pages in depth of the one main menu item, it is active. Then, I click one of the main menu items, for example, Contacts. So, the contacts menu item becomes active. And if I click browser back button, the active menu item won't change.

So, is there any way to remember the state of active main menu item? Main menu is situated on container page.

Thank you!

```
$(function(){

        $('.menu a')
            .bind('click',function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#content').html('Извините, страница не существует или находится в разработке!');
                $('.menu a').each(function() {$(this).removeClass('activelink');});
                location.hash=$(this).attr('href').match(/(([a-z]*)\W)*/)[2];

                $(this).addClass('activelink');
                return false;
            });

        $('#content').on('click','a',function(e) {
            if (!($(this).hasClass('address') || $(this).hasClass('zoom'))){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#content').html('Извините, страница не существует или находится в разработке!');
            location.hash=$(this).attr('href').match(/(([a-z]*)\W)*/)[2];
            return false;
            }
            else {
                if ($(this).hasClass('address')) {
                alert('Вы покидаете сайт The House Of Events. Возвращайтесь к нам еще!');
                }
            }
        });

    function hashChange(){
        var page=location.hash.slice(1);
        if (page!=""){
            $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "content/" + page + ".html #sub-content",
                    success: function(data, status) {
                        $('#content').html(data);
                        },
                    error: function fail() {
                        $('#content').html('Error');
                        }
                });
        }
    }

    if ("onhashchange" in window){
        $(window).on('hashchange',hashChange).trigger('hashchange');
    } else { 
        var lastHash='';
        setInterval(function(){
            if (lastHash!=location.hash)
                hashChange();
            lastHash=location.hash;
        },100);
    }
});
```

Comment: Post code of your main menu to see how it is activating menu items

Comment: check out `history.pushState()`

Comment: The problem is that I don't know, how to determine the main menu item of this submenu page. Or I haven't understood something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a small trick if you strick to hash tags.

Edit these:

```
$('#content').on('click','a',function(e) {
  if(!($(this).hasClass('address') || $(this).hasClass('zoom'))){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#content').html('Извините, страница не существует или находится в разработке!');
    var page=location.hash.slice(1).split('/')[0] + '/' + $(this).attr('href').match(/(([a-z]*)\W)*/)[2];
    location.hash=page;
    return false;
  } else {
    if ($(this).hasClass('address')) {
      alert('Вы покидаете сайт The House Of Events. Возвращайтесь к нам еще!');
    }
  }
});

function hashChange(){
  var page=location.hash.slice(1).split('/')[1];
  if(page==='undefined'){
    page=location.hash.slice(1).split('/')[0];
  }
  if(page!=""){
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "content/" + page + ".html #sub-content",
      success: function(data, status) { $('#content').html(data); },
      error: function fail() { $('#content').html('Error'); }
    });
  }
}
```

You can also use HTML5 history API.

Put this under the click events (delete location hash)

```
var active=$('.menu a.active').attr('id'); // or var active=$('.menu a.active').text();
history.pushState({menu: active}, "Our events", "events.html");
```

Then to change stuff with the back button use `onpopstate`

```
window.onpopstate = function(e){
  if(e.state){
    $('.menu a.activelink).removeClass('activelink')
    $('.menu #'+JSON.stringify(e.state.menu).replace(/"/gi,'')).addClass('activelink');
    var url=window.location.pathname;
    $.ajax({ ... })
  }
}
```

And finali the must stupid way if you add a lot of class to the menu items and check them with `.hasClass()`

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is connected with the pages that is not in main menu. For example, my route was: I've clicked in main menu item "Our events" -> than I found a link on content page to the page "Weddings", clicked it and it was loaded it to my content div. But this page is also a member of "Our events", so it should be active -> than I clicked in main menu to item "Contacts" -> then I clicked browser back button, but it found that there is no link to weddings.html in main menu, so item "Contacts" is still active. And I need an item "Our events" to be active instead "Contacts".

Comment: Then you have two way to do that. First you add classes to the menu which is the name of the child link. The second option is to use HTML5 history API and with that you can use the 'stateObj' handler to add the name of the menu what you want to be active (you need to use JSON). And call that info with 'JSON.stringify(e.state.name_of_the_handler)' to get the data.

Comment: Or you can use yourdomain.com/#/weddings/our_events and then use `location.hash.slice(1).split("/")[1]` . Maybe that's the best solution if you want to use hashtag.

Comment: Thank you! And what is it: {menu: active} what means 'menu' in this context?

Comment: Menu is a JSON handler and active is a variable. Basically you save the id of the active menu into the browser history and whenever the browser call it it's gona parse which menu should be active in a way what JS can read.
Some link if you want to know more:
http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Comment: And what about indexing by Google and other search engines?

Comment: Actually search engines don't run JS. There's a hash-bang (#!) trick for google but non of the other engines use it. Whenever google finds a link like this domain.com/#!posts, it tries to open this domain.com/?_escaped_fragment=posts. Not the best way. If you use HTML5 history API don't forget these: 1. It's not supported by older browsers (You can use in: Firefox 4.0+; Safari 5.0+; Chrome 8.0+; Opera 11.50+; IE 10+). 2. On page refresh the onpopstate is not triggered. 3. Search engines don't support JS they gona check everything under the href attribute.